# Avoiding repetition on javascript prototype definitions - context issue

Tags: javascript, this, es6-modules

I have some javascript code which looks like this - it's very repetitive, and as you can see follows a very defined pattern:

```
var AttachmentBuilder = function(){
    this.attachment = {};
}
AttachmentBuilder.prototype.text = function(value){
    this.attachment.text = value;
    return this;
}
AttachmentBuilder.prototype.fallback = function(value){
    this.attachment.fallback = value;
    return this;
}
 AttachmentBuilder.prototype.color = function(value){
    this.attachment.color = value;
    return this;
}
```

I had the idea to refactor this like:

```
var AttachmentBuilder = function(){
    this.attachment = {};
}
passThrough(AttachmentBuilder.prototype,"attachment","text");
passThrough(AttachmentBuilder.prototype,"attachment","fallback");
passThrough(AttachmentBuilder.prototype,"attachment","color");

function passThrough(obj, apply, name){
    obj[name] = function(param){
        this[apply][name] = param;
    }
    return this;
 }
```

But the context of `this` is not correct, and it does not behave like the long-hand version.

Below is a working example demoing the working and not working versions.

```js
var AttachmentBuilder_Original = function(){
    this.attachment = {};
}
AttachmentBuilder_Original.prototype.text = function(value){
    this.attachment.text = value;
    return this;
}
AttachmentBuilder_Original.prototype.fallback = function(value){
    this.attachment.fallback = value;
    return this;
}
 AttachmentBuilder_Original.prototype.color = function(value){
    this.attachment.color = value;
    return this;
}

var original = new AttachmentBuilder_Original();
original.text("Text").color("Red").fallback("Fallback");
console.log("original",original.attachment);

/* ------------------------------------- */

var AttachmentBuilder_New = function(){
    this.attachment = {};
}
passThrough(AttachmentBuilder_New.prototype,"attachment","text");
passThrough(AttachmentBuilder_New.prototype,"attachment","fallback");
passThrough(AttachmentBuilder_New.prototype,"attachment","color");

function passThrough(obj, apply, name){
    obj[name] = function(param){
        this[apply][name] = param;
    }
    return this;
}

var adjusted = new AttachmentBuilder_New();
adjusted.text("Text").color("Red").fallback("Fallback");
console.log("adjusted",adjusted.attachment);
```

I'm also interested if there is a more ES6-like way of solving this same issue of repetition.

Comment: You meant `return this` inside function?

Comment: It is high time to code in es6 and use a transpiler+bundler for es5 support. Can save you from these hurdles and focus on business logic. *Just a suggestion.*

Comment: And it is a nodeJS project so ES6 away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your higher order function looks good. Probably simple mistake of putting return statement in the wrong place.

```
function passThrough(obj, apply, name){
    obj[name] = function(param){
        this[apply][name] = param;
        return this;
    } //^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thank you for calling me a n00b. Ive only been writing javascript for 25 years! But indeed - I had my `return this` in the wrong place.

Comment: Hmm its probably bad language use. Not that proficient in the language, this happens all the time. I meant simple mistake, sorry if that was bad.

Comment: S'ok. If you have a more ES6-like solution to this problem Im most interested. I am still stuck in old-fashioned JS thinking

Comment: I don't think es6 has anything special related to chaining so I'll better take back my *free* opinion on this. If I find anything related to this pattern I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work, if you do this modification.

```
var AttachmentBuilder = function(){
        this.attachment = {};
    }
    passThrough(AttachmentBuilder.prototype,"attachment","text");
    passThrough(AttachmentBuilder.prototype,"attachment","fallback");
    passThrough(AttachmentBuilder.prototype,"attachment","color");

    function passThrough(obj, apply, name){
        obj[name] = function(param){
            this[apply][name] = param;
            return this;//<---move return this here
        }
        //return this;
     }
```